# Why is internet speed slower when both Ethernet and WLAN interfaces are connected?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dns, ethernet

I've bought a switch to connect my Windows laptop to a computer with Linux I use as storage which has no internet connection.

On the Windows computer I configured my ethernet interface with a fixed IP on the same private network as the Linux one, and that works okay. But I noticed on my Windows computer that WiFi connection is too slow when having both interfaces connected.

At first I thought that may be due to DNS, because it is slow only the first time I access web pages like YouTube. After that first time, subsequent pages and content on that site load quickly and without problems. But I changed to a different DNS server and have the same issues.

What can be happening?

[image: Debian IP configuration]

[image: Windows IP configuration]

Comment: Can you show the actual settings you have?

Comment: Is there anything else connected to Ethernet besides the Linux machine (.2)?

Comment: Sorry, i was uploading the screenshots. There is a switch with the Linux and Windows machine connected. Also, each machine has a connection to the router, the Linux machine also via Ethernet, the Windows one via Wi-Fi.

Comment: You mentioned though that the Linux host has no Internet connection... Can you clarify which of the two networks has a router and which doesn't? The real question though is, does 192.168.0.1 exist?

Comment: Yes, sorry. The Linux host use to have the cable unplugged. In summary: the network 192.168.1.0/24 is the router's one. The Linux machine uses eno1 and the Windows machine uses Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi to connect to that network. The other network, 192.168.0.0/24, was just to connect the two computers without a router. So on the Linux machine I assigned the IP 192.168.0.2/24 to the eno2 interface and on the Windows machine I assigned the 192.168.0.3/24 to Ethernet interface to communicate both via the switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've configured `192.168.0.1` as your Ethernet 'default gateway'. But according to your description, there is *no such device* on the Ethernet network (it only has the two PCs).

Nevertheless, because it is configured, Windows will keep trying to *use* 192.168.0.1 as its default gateway via Ethernet as the primary interface, and will keep sending ARP requests for 192.168.0.1 into the void – until eventually it gives up and decides that this route is not valid.

Do not configure a 'default gateway' for networks that do not in fact have a gateway.